# What is origin mapped to, how to find out

Tags: git

Say you

```
git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:myRepo.git
```

And then .. you know .. you forget what exactly `origin` is mapped to :(

How can you find out?

Comment: `origin` value varies to `.git` content.  `origin` value is different in different repo directories.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
git remote -v
```

will list them. The source for this information can be seen by inspecting `.git/config`:

```
cat .git/config
```

The `config` file in the `.git` directory at the base of your repository contains all the configuration in a plain-text format.

You'll see something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@git.assembla.com:myRepo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The `url` line (in git config parlance, the value of `remote.origin.url`) contains the remote URL.

The other way to find out is by executing `git config remote.origin.url`:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url
git@git.assembla.com:myRepo.git
$
```

Answer (score 8):

```
git remote -v
```

will give a list of all remote along with their corresponding URLs. You can find out even more information about the remote by doing

```
git remote show origin
```

Read more in the [man page for `git-remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can run the following command:

```
git remote -v
```

to get a list of all remotes with their URL.

From the man-page:

> OPTIONS
>    -v, --verbose
>     Be a little more verbose and show remote url after name. NOTE: This must be placed between remote and
>                  subcommand.
>
> COMMANDS
>    With no arguments, shows a list of existing remotes. Several subcommands are available to perform operations
>              on the remotes.